# Why is Terraform Not Picking My Object Resource?

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform-provider-aws

I have tried many times yet Terraform can't see my object resource. What could be wrong with my code?
My bucket and bucket website resource gets created, but the object resource doesn't.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "My_bucket" {
  bucket = "my-test-bucket-for-cloudfront"
  tags = {
    Name = "My bucket"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "public_bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.id

  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "object" {
  # Use a for loop to grab every file in the folder.
  # The fileset() function is used to read all the files in a folder
  for_each = fileset("/travel-agency-html-template/", "**")
  bucket = "my-test-bucket-for-cloudfront"
  # Use each.value to grab every file inside the folder
  key    = each.value
  source = "/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}"
  acl = "public-read"
  etag = filemd5("travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}")

  depends_on = [ aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket ]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "travel_agency" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.id

  index_document {
    suffix = "/travel-agency-html-template/index.html"
  }

  error_document {
    key = "/travel-agency-html-template/404.html"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you currently have the `fileset` specified is that it searches within the folder `/travel-agency-html-template` at the root of your file system. I doubt that is where the files are actually located. Instead you should e.g. use

```
fileset("${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template", "**")
```

depending on where the files are actually located relative to your terraform code.

Comment: I simply want to upload all of the files inside the folder.

Comment: @charlesuneze understandable, but you need to be way clearer in what "the folder" is. As I said `/travel-agency-html-template` points to the root level which is probably not where the images are.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked, thank you so much! What does the variable ${path.module} do when it is added to the folder path?Also kindly explain why two ** were used.

Comment: Omg, so I only did a “terraform plan” but as I did a “terraform apply -auto-approve” now, I got a ‘no such file or directory’

Comment: Check what the `source` of the object in your plan was, it is once again using an absolute root path starting at `/travel...`. Apart from that: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/fileset#-1

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the path.module variable in all file paths.

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "object" {
  # Use a for loop to grab every file in the folder.
  # The fileset() function is used to read all the files in a folder
  # Use the path.module variable to locate the file path.
  for_each = fileset("${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template", "**")
  bucket = "my-test-bucket-for-cloudfront"
  
  # Use each.value to grab every file inside the folder
  key    = "${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}"
  source = "${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}"
  etag = filemd5("${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}")

  depends_on = [ aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket ]
}
```

Comment: The key does not need to be identical to the local path, you *can* obviously do that but that is not strictly needed.